# gdb show local file frames in thread list

Tags: c++, gdb, deadlock

I'm debugging C++ deadlocks with gdb. Inevitably all the deadlock frames are deep inside library functions. For example, `__lll_lock_wait` is found several layers under `mutex::lock()`. It would be really great if I could just glance at the thread list to deduce where the deadlock is happening instead of going through the backtrace for each thread.

## Example

### main.cpp

In this example I purposely introduce deadlock by trying to lock the same mutex twice.

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

void lock_a(){
    std::mutex a;
    a.lock();
    // attempt to lock something that's already locked
    a.lock();
}

int main(){
    std::thread t_a(lock_a);
    t_a.join();
    return 0;
}
```

### compilation & running

```sh
clang++ -g main.cpp -lpthread -o main.exe
gdb -ex run --args ./main.exe
```

### gdb

Here I'm trying to figure out what caused the deadlock. If `info threads` could somehow prioritize  "local" files I might find the cause much faster. At long last I'm able to see that I'm trying to lock a mutex in `main.cpp`

```
(gdb) info threads 
  Id   Target Id                                      Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7ffff7a41740 (LWP 2651239) "main.exe" __pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=140737348110080, thread_return=0x0, 
    clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:145
  2    Thread 0x7ffff7a40700 (LWP 2651293) "main.exe" __lll_lock_wait (futex=futex@entry=0x7ffff7a3fe08, private=0) at lowlevellock.c:52
(gdb) t 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0x7ffff7a40700 (LWP 2651293))]
#0  __lll_lock_wait (futex=futex@entry=0x7ffff7a3fe08, private=0) at lowlevellock.c:52
52  lowlevellock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) f 4
#4  0x0000000000401223 in lock_a () at main.cpp:8
8       a.lock();
```

Is there some way to have gdb prioritize certain files when listing threads?

Comment: You may try to write your own python scripts and load it with gdb, seem this example: https://github.com/DamZiobro/gdb-automatic-deadlock-detector

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm skeptical the specific `gdb-automatic-deadlock-detector` project will solve my needs because I'm having a lot of threads wait on condition variables / semaphores. I'm getting deadlock waiting for new data to come in.

Comment: So can I turn the comment into an answer, there are some other similar projects which would be helpful too.